# Coercion from Python not allowed without the GIL, using arrays in parallel (multithreading in Cython)

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading, cython

```
void worker(int *P,int l):
  cdef i

  with nogil, parallel():
    for i in prange(l):
        P[i]=1
```

I'm trying to use arrays in cython with multithreading.. but i get this error:

> Coercion from Python not allowed without the GIL

the array P is initialized like this:

```
cdef int l=500000

cdef int *P=<int *> malloc(l* sizeof(int))
```

any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a type (e.g. `cdef i`) then `i` is a Python object. Therefore you are not allowed to use `i` within a `nogil` block. You probably want `cdef int i` or similar to specify that `i` is a C integer.